# alternative for this componentWillMount case?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I'm trying to refactor some old code.

`componentWillMount` has been deprecated.

How would I refactor it here into something else?

```
class Detail extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        logged_out_redirect: true
    };
}   

componentWillMount() {  //<------ this lifecycle method has been deprecated, how do I replace it?

    if (localStorage.getItem("JWT")) {
        this.setState({logged_out_redirect: false});
    }
}

render() {

    if (this.state.logged_out_redirect) {
        return (<Redirect to={"/login"}/>)
    }

    return (        )

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case(depend on case what you're trying to do in `componentWillMount`). You cant put it inside your `constructor()`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    logged_out_redirect: localStorage.getItem("JWT") ? false : true
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`. This will be invoked for the first time and for any subsequent update.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("JWT") && state.logged_out_redirect) {
        return {logged_out_redirect: false};
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with `componenDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {   
    if (localStorage.getItem("JWT")) {
        this.setState({logged_out_redirect: false});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. I already tried it. Here's why it doesn't work. The render method contains `if (this.state.logged_out_redirect) {
        return (<Redirect to={"/login"}/>) }`. By the time it mounts, it's already re-directed to another component. So `componentDidMount` either doesn't fire or fires too late.